# Apache VirtualHost not functioning properly on Centos 7 server

Tags: centos7, virtualhost, grafana, httpd.conf, metabase

I have two different web applications running on port 3000 (grafana) and port 3001 (metabase) as you can see below:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I have set up apache virtualhost in /etc/httpd/conf.d/default-site.conf as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /metabase/ http://127.0.0.1:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse /metabase/ http://127.0.0.1:3001/
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I try to access this using domainname.com/metabase/ it does not route there but instead routes to grafana running on port 3000.

How can I configure Apache to route my requests to metabase?

Comment: The configuration you have provided seems to be incomplete.

Comment: @aventurin am new to this, can you tell me what more do I need to do?

Comment: Provide a more complete configuration. At least the Grafana part seems to be missing.

Comment: @aventurin Grafana was already running on 3000. I installed apache as I wanted to run metabase. When I tested if apache was running, instead of showing TEST 123 page it showed the grafana login. So I made a virtualhost for metabase. However When I hit domainname.com/metabase it was still routing me to grafana login. I have not done any configurations for grafana